# How to use 'nor' without 'neither'

Tags: sentence-construction

Is this sentence correct?

> He gave them no money nor did he help them.

I know *neither nor* is followed by the same auxiliary verb. But, is this also true to the sentences which uses nor without neither?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but closely related: [http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/21044/32]

Answer (score 2):

This is good question.

Okay, the sentence structure seems incorrect.

Whilst *neither...nor* is quite a popular format, *nor* without *neither* is to be used cautiously.

Using *nor* alone refers to *and..not* **or** *or not*. I don't smoke. Nor do I drink.

From the [Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/libertycentral/2010/apr/22/google-internet-freedom-privacy):

> *Google alone cannot, and should not, bear this burden. It is a company, not a human rights organisation. **Nor** is it a state.*

Having this said, your sentence can be rephrased as (one of the ways):

> He did not give them money. Nor did he help them.

[Further reading here.](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Can_you_use_nor_without_neither?#slide=1)

Comment: I don't see why the rephrasing is needed. For example, *"Mithrandir never spoke to us of what was to be, nor did he reveal his purposes."* --Lord of the Rings.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I said *one of the ways* and I rephrased it to make OP understand and match with the standard examples I gave.